# Find when two sin graphs hit $x=0$ at the same time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Lets say I have 2 sine functions. They could be any sine functions but I'm more interested in the ones that get bigger/smaller as they go.
So we have:
$$
y_1 = \sin{(x^2)}
$$
$$
y_2=\sin{\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}
$$

I'm interested in when they both hit $y=0$ at the same time.

I don't know where to even start.

Comment: Do you know for which values of $u$ we have $\sin u = 0$?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth $\sin(x^2)= 0$ for $\sqrt{n\pi}; n>0$, and $\sin(\sqrt{x}) = 0$ for $n^2\pi^2; n>0$

Answer (score 0):

You have $x^2 = \pi n$ and $\sqrt{x} = \pi m$. Eliminating $x$ gives $n = \pi^3 m^4$. As $\pi$ is irrational $m$ must be 0, and hence $x = 0$ is the only solution.